# How to encode a django query set specific field to a Json response?

Tags: django, django-models

I do a filter to obtain a particular set of objects from django data model. I need to encode only a single field of that objects to a json response.

e.g.: Item has an attribute called **name**.

```
qs_available = Item.objects.filter(Type=1).values.('name').???

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(qs_available), content_type='application/json')
```

How do I return the list of name values as a json response?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JsonResponse from django.http,

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

qs_available = Item.objects.filter(Type=1).values_list('name')
return JsonResponse(list(qs_available), safe=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only names list, you can use values_list

```
qs_available = list(Item.objects.filter(Type=1).values_list('name', flat=True))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(qs_available), content_type='application/json')
```